# How to addressing package view on Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, addressing, laravel-blade

I have modules folder in root directory Laravel 5.1.
and located a package as test1 in this.
Also I have file view1.blade.php in this directory

```
resources/views/view1.blade.php
```

How to can access in View1.blade.php from this address

```
modules/test1/View/test.blade.php
```

I use this command in View1 file but not work correctly

```
@include "modules/test1/View/test";
```

and this command

```
@include('modules::test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a name for view in `PackageSeviceProvider` like this:

```
// Define path for view files
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/View','PackageView');
```

and in Blade Template use:

```
@include ('PackageView::Addpage')
```